# Why it is an error to ignore a rejected promise on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I don't want to do anything if the promise is rejected, like `getPromise().then(foo=>{});`. Why is it an error on Chrome?

```
(new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{reject()}))
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
VM3250:2 Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

On Node and Firefox, it is OK to ignore the rejected part.

Answer (score 5):

Promise rejection is like uncaught exception.
if you want to ignore exception - catch it, but don't handle,
same here - add `.catch` statement, but do nothing

`Promise.reject(new Error('bad..')).catch(e => {})`

I would not however recommend that, as promises reject for a reason, so you might want to add some sort of handling logic

Comment: do I have to? Can I just ignore it?

Comment: @stackers you dont have to, but like I said in the answer promise rejection is like uncaught exception  - it will show in your console in red, as an error. Any logic you may have depending on promise resolution **will not execute**

Answer (score 3):

Without a promise reject handler, chrome would throws reason of the rejection *asynchronously* that doesn't effects any JavaScript process, just prints the reason to console. If you get annoyed with this, you need to add handler, e.g. `Promise.reject(reason).catch(reason => {})`.

**UPDATE:** Why is an error? It may be because rejection is conventionally considered as an exception (an error).

P.S. Your "question" look like a feedback rather than a question. I personally prefer getting the reason as an error.

Comment: This exception does have effect when I use `Promise` in extension, content-script. The whole extension is aborted with only one line message: `Uncaught (in promise)          undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Rejecting a promise basically means something bad happened, and that you should be handling it with a call to `catch`. If you reject a promise without having a `catch`, it will throw an exception (more accurately, an unhandled rejection)

```
var a = (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("my error")
})).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
})
```

I'm guessing it is a specificity of V8 if this happens only under Chrome, but it makes sense to me